# Why the file fonts.dir.back can't be commited?

Tags: git

```
ls     
Desktop    fonts.dir.back  Downloads 
git add fonts.dir.back    
git commit -m  'mytest'    
On branch master   
Untracked files:
nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Why the file fonts.dir.back can't be commited?

Comment: Seems you are at home folder. It's not proper to initialize home as a git repo. You could delete the invisible folder `.git` to make home non git repo. Make a new folder to do your test.

Comment: Is it really a file? Or ist it a (possibly empty) directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the file is not being ignored :

```
git check-ignore fonts.dir.back
```

The output of that should tell you if there is a git ignore rule preventing that file from being added.